# Can I Refresh Tableau Database automatically using bat file

Tags: database, refresh, tableau-api

I have a tableau containing lots of databases in it to refresh databases i need to run following command again and again by changing parameters

> C:\Program Files\Tableau\Tableau 10.2\bin>tableau refreshextract --server https://online.tableau.com --username email@domain.com --password "OurServerPwd" --site vernazza --project "New Animations" --datasource "CurrentYrOverYrStats" --original-file "\server\path\filename.csv"

```
refresh successful 
672345 rows uploaded
```

... I want something that will automated this process , so i use bat. file
Following is my bat file content
`cd C:\Program Files\Tableau\Tableau 10.2\bin`

> tableau refreshextract --server https://online.tableau.com --username email@domain.com --password "OurServerPwd" --site vernazza --project "New Animations" --datasource "CurrentYrOverYrStats" --original-file "\server\path\filename.csv"

while running the bat file it is showing incorrect userid or password
contradictory i used the same user id and password as i used in bat file and while running through cmd prompt its showing refresh successful

Answer (score 0):

I refresh a single extract with the following bat file script. I haven't tried multiple data sources. I use the `timeout /T -1` during testing and you can add `REM` to the line or delete if you like.

```
 tabcmd logout

 tabcmd login -s serverAddress -u user -p password 
 timeout /T -1

 tabcmd refreshextracts --datasource "revenue recognized"
 timeout /T -1

 tabcmd logout
 timeout /T -1
```

When I first started using this I was receiving an error if I was logged in and tried `tabcmd login` again. I resolved this by logging out at the beginning of the script just in case and that solved it.

Try to simplify your refresh as much as possible to start testing. Start with a data source that is in the default site and remove any unnecessary commands involving site and workbook. This should simplify it until you get the script working properly.

Comment: Thanks vizyourdata ur reply some what helped me but my issue is different as i said earlier i dnt have any problem in running tableau command directly through cmd prompt but while i am running it using batch file it giving me error

Comment: Let me explain what I am trying to do.....
I have a tableau server on which various databases are stored my task is to refresh that databases and after refreshing them there output should get stored in some file (Log file)
so basically my file have following content

Comment: 1, RefreshStarted,<Refresh Starting Time>,<Data Source Name>,<Output after running command>,<Refresh Ending Time>,<Status successful/failed>

Comment: now i am trying to running that command and storing its output in a variable but while doing so it gives me message that "Tableau is Not internal or External Command"

Comment: Hi Rahul. I have the script above in a .bat file. did you try it in a .bat?

Comment: yes i used the above script but still its giving same error just instead of tableau it is saying 
//`tabcmd is not internal or external command`

Comment: You may have to add tabcmd to your environment variables or first navigate to where it is installed locally. Add this to the top of your .bat file `cd c:\program files\tableau\tableau server\<SERVER VERSION>\extras\command line utility`

Comment: `tabcmd refreshextracts` command dont give the no. of rows updated on other hand `tableau refreshextracts` give the no of rows updated but when i am trying to get its input in a txt file or in a variable it is creating a blank text file and with tabcmd command i am able to get file with output but output dnt have the no of rows updated